# why my push() works like set() in firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am following the tutorial on Firebase, and I am trying to push data that user filled in a  form to the firebase. I used

`ref.push({name:name, atomsphere:atomsphere, temperature:temperature});`

but it works like `ref.set()`. It rewrite the database overtime rather than creating a list. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: you must have missed something, can you show the rest of your code/js/html

Comment: That instruction should create a list as you expect. So there's probably something else going on. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle or jsbin and post the link? Feel free to use `'https://lisaso.firebaseio-demo.com/` for the Firebase if you don't like using your own Firebase for this.

Comment: thank you! @FrankvanPuffelen i tested with your database, then it works... i used the formly-form. i realize i need to push the whole model rather than individual items. does it make sense?

Comment: Hi Lisa. I have no idea what the "formly-form" is. Can you try reproducing the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ and sharing the link here? That will make it much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: It is library, http://angular-formly.com/#/ sorry, i tried, but could not really reproduce the problem here....http://jsbin.com/yivapatohi/1/edit. The problem was solved though